# How to enter string value into Delta PLC?

Tags: string, plc, ladder-logic

I would like to insert string value into PLC, I searched a lot of information but unable to get an accurate method to do it. The plc that I using is DVP-14SS2 and I using wplsoft as the software to edit ladder diagram. Someone can guide me on how to enter string value into PLC? I'll appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

The DVP model PLC does not support Strings, as pointed out in [this manual](http://www.deltronics.ru/images/manual/ISPSoft_UM_EN_20170614.pdf) (PDF is for ISPSOFT but I believe this definition applies to WPLSOFT too, I couldn't find reference to it, as you...).

But depending on your needs, as this PLC supports ARRAY of WORDS, you could try to write the ASCII code and manipulate it manually.

[image: ISPSoft Manual - Item 7.2.2 - Page 7-5]